# What is the relationship between 'taste' and 'flavor' in particle physics?

Tags: field-theory, terminology, fermions, lattice-model

This paper, among others, discusses 'taste symmetry.'  What is it talking about, and how does it relate to flavor?

Reference: Borsanyi, S., Fodor, Z., Guenther, J.N. *et al.* Leading hadronic contribution to the muon magnetic moment from lattice QCD. *Nature* (2021). https://doi.org/10.1038/s41586-021-03418-1

Comment: The linked paper is behind a paywall. A [related preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.12347).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Tastes" is the name for the additional fermions produced by [fermion doubling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermion_doubling) when putting actions with fermions on a  lattice. "Taste symmetry" is a symmetry exchanging these additional fermions with each other.

These "tastes" are unphysical and purely an artifact of the lattice theory - they have no relation to flavor except for being an obvious play on the name. A major part of lattice computations is figuring out how to relate the results of the lattice theory with additional "tastes" to the continuum theory without them that you want to approximate.